# Trouble understanding array appending

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

```
func EmptySearchBarList(){

self.PersonalSearchesList = []

currentUserFirebaseReference.child("rooms").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in


    if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
        for snap in snapshots {

            print("snap")
            print(self.PersonalSearchesList.count) // Calling 0 every single time

            DataService.ds.REF_INTERESTS.child(interestKey).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in

                if snapshot.value != nil {

                    if let users = (snapshot.value! as? NSDictionary)?["users"] as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject> {

                        DataService.ds.REF_USERS.child(topUser).child("pictureURL").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in

                            self.PersonalSearchesList.append(eachSearch)
                            print("first one")
                            print(self.PersonalSearchesList.count)
                        })
                    }
                }
            })

        }

        print("Second one")
        print(self.PersonalSearchesList.count)

        print("Calling to set my sorted PersonalSearchesList")
        self.mySortedList = self.PersonalSearchesList.sorted{ $0.users > $1.users }

    }
}
initialLoadOver = true
}
```

[image: The print logs]

What code I'm trying to ultimately run is this :

```
 var mySortedList = [Interest](){
    didSet{
        print("this was called")
        let myCount = mySortedList.count
        print(self.PersonalSearchesList.count)
        print(myCount)

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

The attempt is to load up my PersonalSearchesList array, and once the snap in snapshots is done running, I'm setting MySortedList equal to PersonalSearchesList and reloading the tableview.

What I don't understand is why  the prints are coming out like they are.  The snap/ 0's are coming from the top of my for snap in snapshots. It seems like it should instead be snap / 1 , snap / 2, snap / 3.

The code to be called when the snaps are done is correct in the timeline, once the snaps have gone through that code runs. What doesn't make sense is why it's not until after that the items are actually being appended to PersonalSearchesList. Becuase of how everything is Im' setting my filtered array to an empty personal searches array and then afterwards I'm filling it up.

Any ideas here?

edit:

```
 var dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
        dispatchGroup.enter()
        dispatchGroup.leave()

        dispatchGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.global(), execute: {

        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataService.ds.REF_INTERESTS.child(interestKey).observeSingleEvent` is running asynchronous so all of those callbacks (where you actually fill you list) will run when they are called from the DataService.

You could use a `dispatch group` to do what you want. 
http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2014/03/19/using-dispatch-groups-to-wait-for-multiple-web-services/

```
func EmptySearchBarList(){
var dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()    
self.PersonalSearchesList = []


currentUserFirebaseReference.child("rooms").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in


    if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
        for snap in snapshots {
            dispatchGroup.enter()
```

single time

```
            DataService.ds.REF_INTERESTS.child(interestKey).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in

                if snapshot.value != nil {

                    if let users = (snapshot.value! as? NSDictionary)?["users"] as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject> {

                        DataService.ds.REF_USERS.child(topUser).child("pictureURL").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in

                            self.PersonalSearchesList.append(eachSearch)
                            print("snap")
                            print(self.PersonalSearchesList.count)
                        })
                    }
                }
                dispatchGroup.leave()
            })

        }

        dispatchGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.global(), execute: {
            print("Second one")
            print(self.PersonalSearchesList.count)

            print("Calling to set my sorted PersonalSearchesList")
            self.mySortedList = self.PersonalSearchesList.sorted{ $0.users > $1.users }
        })


    }
}
initialLoadOver = true
}
```

I'm not completely sure you can enter and leave the group several times from the same thread so you might have to wrap the code from enter until the end of the callback in another thread and call it async

Comment: I edited in the code I think I was meant to pull from that site. It looks like the general concept is to make a queue, enter it, exit it, and then at the point you exit the queue? or it's done everything in the queue?..and then at that point you run what code you're wanting to run. 

So in my case I'd define the queue up at the top, enter in at the start of my observer..? end at where I'm currently calling "second one", and then inside of the notification run the my sorted list bit? 

I might be wayyy off here, so bear with me.

Comment: Went ahead and gave ya the answer because I think you've told me all that I need to be able to fix this but I'm getting the same results with whatcha gave me. 

When I'm printing PersonalSearchesList.count I'm getting 0. 

So with your 2nd reccomendation I'd create another group, start before I enter, end after I end in the first one, then call the notify on the whole thing elsewhere?